# Moving the login form to a lightbox

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, ajax, login

I am building my first ever site with magento. And I'm trying to create a popup with the login form in it. How can I load the content of the login page in a block or in a template?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I load the complete block at the page load. But i wanted to load it via ajax. Is it possible?

Comment: Try this https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible out of the box.  You'd need to create a custom extension to do it.  The development of that custom extension is longer than a single Stack Exchange question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a free ajax login extension like this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lite-ajax-login-1247.html

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I'm not going to flag this because it is a free extension which does what the OP wants but just bear in mind that link-only self promotional answers are frowned on here.  This ain't the Magento boards. If you post a link to your own extension then say it's your extension, and add in more detail to the answer which will make this page a worthwhile resource for the future.